# Why do some faces of my model show up like this? I also cannot create any loop cut that runs through them

Tags: modeling

[image: Something is making the faces appear in a different color. I've merged by distance with varying distances to remove any possible doubles but nothing helps...]

Something is making these faces appear this way. I can't loop cut through them, and overall it's bothering me. Something looks like it's not right. I tried merging by distance to remove any doubles but nothing helps...

Comment: Looks like the case for the Sony ANC earplugs (WH-1000XM3) ;-)

Comment: @U.Windl yup, it's what i'm trying to make

Answer (score 3):

Check the direction of the normals. Mesh > Normals > Recalculate

Answer (score 1):

The hole on the bottom is wrong, you create some ngons and poles. Boolean is not a good way for modeling if you want further adjustment. Adding some cuts usually meaningless, the hole should be rebuild.Try to learn something about modelling, there are many tutorials.

Comment: I guess before judging him for the use of booleans, he should rather correct the orientation of the faces.